# Import tsv using IMPORTDATA in google docs, delimiter wrong (treated as csv)

Tags: google-apps-script, csv

I want to import a tsv file to a spreadsheet in Google Docs. The file has tab separated values but it is not named *.tsv
Since it contains some values with a comma, it is treated as a csv. Is there a way to set a delimiter flag? The IMPORTDATA function should cover both csv and tsv.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the parseCsv function under the Utilities library.
The function takes comma as the default delimiter, however you do have the option to specify a custom delimiter using the overloaded function parseCsv(csv, delimiter). 
In your case you must keep in mind that the delimiter needs to be specified explicitly in bot h cases, the program has no way of automatically figuring out the delimiter.

Comment: there is no second parameter in `IMPORTDATA`, it just opens tsv without it, not sure why there were so many `+1` for that comment, but it fails when adding it, no matter what

Comment: tested and IMPORTDATA reacts to the second parameter, in my case ";". See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937539/parse-tab-separated-text-file-in-google-sheets