# Parse tab separated text file in Google Sheets

Tags: csv, google-sheets

I have a txt file available on the web which contains tab separated values  (TSV/CSV) like this:

> Product_Id`tab`Color`tab`Price`tab`Quantity
> Item1        `tab`Red  `tab`$5.2 `tab`5
> Item2        `tab`Blue `tab`$7.5 `tab`10

I imported the txt file into a Google Spreadsheet using the `IMPORTDATA(url)` formula. The problem is that now I need to split the text to columns. I tried the following formulas without success:

```
Split(A1,"\t")
Split(A1,"    ")
Split(A1,"<tab>")
```

another thing I tried is to to use the `Substitute` function, but I just can't figure out how to match the `Tab` character in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: `IMPORTDATA()` should handle the tabs automatically, if the file extension is `.tsv`. Is there any way you can control that?

Comment: Confirmed - same file with name `*.tsv` gets imported properly.

Comment: If you cannot change the source file extension, like @Mogsdad suggested, you may try the simple workaround suggested in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48840679/4244835) below.

Answer (score 18):

Pages strips tabs by default when you paste text using a standard paste. Tab delimited data can be pasted and automatically parsed using:

Right Click -> Paste special -> Paste values only

Comment: The question explicitly mentions importing data using the `IMPORTDATA(url)` function in a formula, not manually importing. This answer does not seem to address that.

Answer (score 8):

IMPORTDATA(url) seems to handle tabs automatically, as others have mentioned before, if the **URL** ends in ".tsv".

I had trouble trying to import a file from Dropbox even though the file was named "something.tsv", because the url was

```
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/something.tsv?dl=1"
```

I managed to solve the problem by adding a dummy query parameter to the url:

```
"https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/something.tsv?dl=1&x=.tsv"
```

Comment: This is a brilliantly simple solution!

Answer (score 5):

**NOTE:** I know this question was asked back in 2014 and I am answering this question some 5 years later. I am posting the answer here in hopes that someone else who googles their way here will be saved the headache and can be helped by how I devised a solution.

**SUMMARY OF THE ISSUE:** By default the IMPORTDATA() function will properly process a tab-delimited file only if the file name ends with the extension .TSV

**UPDATE Nov 14, 2019:**
In a comment below, Poul shared that he has found an [undocumented parameter](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) for the IMPORTDATA() function by which you can specify the delimiter to split the data. As of writing this, the [official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) makes no reference to this delimiter.
[image]

In effect the documentation should look something like the following:

```
IMPORTDATA("url","delimiter")
```

So, if you wanted to force a file to be split on the TAB character, it would look something like

```
IMPORTDATA("url","\t")
```

---

**PRIOR ANSWER:**

UPDATE: I am leaving my original answer just in case it might be helpful if the answer above, which includes undocumented functionality, does not continue to work.

ORIGINAL ANSWER: After seemingly countless attempts, I figured out how to coax Google Sheets into importing a tab-delimited file regardless of the extension.

For those looking for the quick and dirty answer, copy the following into a cell of a Google Sheet to give it a try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(SPLIT(IMPORTDATA("https://iso639-3.sil.org/sites/iso639-3/files/downloads/iso-639-3_Latin1.tab"),CHAR(9),FALSE,FALSE)))
```

---

For those that want to know a bit more, I will try to explain how each of the nested functions are helping to create the final solution:

=ARRAYFORMULA( IFERROR( SPLIT( IMPORTDATA(URL-HERE) ,CHAR(9),FALSE,FALSE) ) )

[`IMPORTDATA()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335?hl=en) - the primary function that pulls in the data file from the web

[`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) - split the row by tab, note the use of char(09) to generate the tab character; also note the use of FALSE for the last parameter which was required in my case to ensure empty cells were not collapsed together

[`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en) - used to catch situations where an import might fail, the error will be trapped and not returned to the spreadsheet

[`ARRAYFORMULA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) - this function ensures that every line in the file is parsed; without this, only the first line of the file would be returned to the spreadsheet

Comment: "I am posting the answer here in hopes that someone else who googles their way here" good point!
For the same sake posting will post here that:
It's find out that IMPORTDATA() function can accept parameter, which directly specify delimiter (while this doesn't stated in spec.)
i.e. IMPORTDATA("url","delimiter")
for tab delimiter it's should be "\t"

Comment: Thank you Poul for the answer. I have updated my answer above to include your very helpful find.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that [`IMPORTDATA(url)`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093335) **can** import a tab separated file, but it expects the file name to have the `.tsv` extension. This is inconsistent with Excel, where a tab-separated export results in `*.txt`.

If you can ensure that you use a `.tsv` extension, then your problem is solved.

You can also use the Sheets UI to import the file (into a new Spreadsheet). Select `File > Import...`, then `Upload > Select a file from your computer`. When the file selection dialog opens, paste the URL into the `file name` field, and click `Open`. The file will be downloaded to your PC then uploaded to Drive, through the Import dialog that will let you choose the delimiter.

(Validated on Windows 8.1 with Chrome; I don't know how this will behave on other OSes or browsers.)

---

Edit: See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mogsdad/7977853f69fd7cdc8fa0#csvutilsgs).

```
 importFromCSV(string fileName, string sheetName)
```

Populates a sheet with contents read from a CSV file located in the user's GDrive. If either parameter is not provided, the function will open inputBoxes to obtain them interactively.

***Automatically detects tab or comma delimited input.***

Answer (score 1):

This could be done in two steps leveraging the fact that `tab` is essentially multiple `space`s.

Steps are as follows:

1. Select the columns which have tab separated data. Then trim tab to single space by using `Data` -> `Data cleanup` -> `Trim whitespaces`.
2. Now usual `Data` -> `Split text to columns` should work out of the box or after selecting space as separator.

Answer (score 0):

I had luck using split() and indicating only a single space as the delimiter, even though the data i pasted in had tabs separating each "column": `=SPLIT(A1, " ", True)` where A1 had data separated by 1 or more spaces.  It seems that pasting in TSV data results in conversion from tabs to spaces.